# Convert complex text date to mysql format

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have dates in an excel file in this format: `Mon, 12 Sep 2022 19:30:16 UTC` but I want to upload the CSV data to a mySQL database that requires `yyyy-mm-dd` as the format.

I've tried all the functions like DATE, DATEVALUE, etc, etc. but can't get all the pieces back together and have the date just saved as simple text in the `yyyy-mm-dd` (versus MS date serial or similar).

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to use custom format (for the required format `yyyy-mm-dd`)?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I've tried a few things, but can't get anything to match with the day of the week and the ```UTC``` at the end.

Comment: Are your dates actually in that format (as in, typed in as text) or just shown in that format? If it's the latter, the Format command should work.

Comment: Also, which language/region setting do you use? For instance, my Excel is in English but my localization is Netherlands, so I have to use =FORMAT(A1;"jjjj-mm-dd").

Comment: @Paul This is english in the US. And yes, the dates are actually in that format in text. They came this way from an export from another platform.

Comment: The computer doesn't care about the day of the week and you could strip it off.  The computer can compute the day of the week if need be.   =MID(A1,FIND(",",A1,1)+1,LEN(A1))

Comment: @cybernard I can get to ```12 Sep 2022```, but can't get to this format from there ```yyyy-mm-dd```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For English-US, and assuming the dates are always text strings in the exact format you show, then try:

```
=TEXT(--MID(A1, 6,11),"yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Comment: This worked PERFECTLY! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you can get to `12 Sep 2022`, you only need one more thing:  wrap the formula getting you to there in the `VALUE` function and Excel should convert it to the "date number" which can then be formatted as you please.

However you do that, it just needs that last step. So perhaps:

```
=VALUE(  TEXTAFTER(LEFT(TEXTBEFORE(F1,":"),LEN(TEXTBEFORE(F1,":"))-3),", ")  )
```

It is possible that won't do it, perhaps, due to possible choices in the operating system's settings, but also possible not so. I shan't be experimenting and maybe not setting everything back, but you surely can.

There are MANY ways you can generate the "date number" Excel needs. A simple one, going from where you've reached (if the operating system settings preclude `VALUE` from succeeding), would be to separate the three values separated by spaces and use the month name in a lookup in a table (hide the table away in a Named Range:  create the table in cells, then use the strict version of `ARRAYTOTEXT` to convert it to a string, edit every other comma separator to be a semi-colon separator, copy and paste values, then copy that into the Named Range inside the curly brackets/braces of `={}`, or just type it out). The lookup would be the three-character month abbreviations and the returned value would be the matching month numbers. Then wrap that result in `DATE` using it and the other two pieces from your splitting of `12 Sep 2022`.

Or use the "perhaps like this" I gave at the start.

Comment: ```TEXTAFTER``` doesn't appear to be a function in my version of excel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a fairly simple way to do this. If you don't have a recent Excel version with TEXTAFTER and TEXTSPLIT, then just use text-to-columns, delimited by spaces, and use VALUE on the three cells representing year, month and day to get a serial date. Then, you can use FORMAT to achieve any format you want.